How does Dua really work?
For example, if i am lazy and i make dua to Allah to not make me lazy, will i suddendly become energetic and active? Or if i am a dumb person and i make dua to Allah to make me smart and give me knowledge do i suddendly become smart? If to become smart i have to read and learn, then what is the point of making dua anyway? All i can think of where dua is helpfull is for the hereafter, for Allah's forgiveness, to go to Jannah etc. What if you make dua and pray salah for weeks and months and nothing has changed in your life? Is it because i am not making dua like i am supposed to or the dua has not been accepted?

Allah is the All-Powerful All-Creator of the Universe, He's not some genie in a bottle that gives you three wishes whenever you rub Him.
Du'a is asking Allah for help, not demanding it. It's about acknowledging ones own limits, not about any expectations of what one may get in return. One asks for help because they acknowledge that they need help.
Du'a is about humility, about recognizing the fact that we are not all-powerful, that no matter how much we try, how hard we work, we have no actual control over what happens to us. You mention working hard to become smart, but the truth is some people can spend their whole lives reading and learning and still end up no smarter than average, while others can be brilliant without ever opening a book. Same way some people can struggle to get out of bed every day while others are full of motivation, or how one person can be born rich while another will work all their life and barely scrape a living wage. All you really have control over is how much effort you put into it, but the results are ultimately still up to Allah.
The point of du'a isn't about whether Allah gives you what you want, it's about recognizing that it was always Allah's to give, not yours to take. Whether your du'a is accepted is ultimately up to Allah's will: He may give you what you want, He may withhold it, He may give you something better.
